# How to authorize application to post to Facebook User's Wall?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using GAE, Python and the Facebook-Python SDK to build an application.  I've got FB login working, have a Facebook Application set up of course and am now trying to use the Graph API to post a message on my Wall from the app.

When I attempt to POST to Facebook I get the response:

*GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action*

How do I authorize the application to perform that action?  When I log into my application via Facebook, I was initially asked to "allow" the application rights.  Is there another step I am missing?

UPDATE: perhaps I am not requesting access to the publishing stream?

Here is my javascript for the login process:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: '{{ facebook_app_id }}', status: true, cookie: true,
           xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('{% if current_user %}auth.logout{% else %}auth.login{% endif %}', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
};
```

Do I need to also call FB.login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

There are 6 extended permissions params you can pass to the login button: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: For example: <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="publish_checkins,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>